# time input validation with start time and end time using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add start time and end time dynamically using JavaScript:

Below is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<table id="timeTable" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Start Time" value="" id="vTime" class="vTime" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter End Time" value="" id="vTime" class="vTime" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#timeTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('#add-more').click(function () {
  var vTime = $(".vTime:last-child").last().val();
  $('#myTable').append('<tr><td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter Start Time" class="vTime" /></td><td><input type="text" placeholder="Enter End Time" value="" id="vTime" class="vTime" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td></tr>');
});
```

If I enter start time and end time first time then end time should not be less that start time, when I enter second row for start and end time then it should not be less than previous time and so on....

Can anyone please help?

Here is jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pathik2012/45La1q0s/5/

Comment: what is your time format?

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of validation?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph HH:MM

Comment: @Andreas I got last entered time but don't know what to do..

Comment: why not have timepicker or type time? or do you really want user to enter the time?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph want to enter manual..

Comment: @PathikVejani so HH:MM mean 24h format?

Comment: @NidhinJoseph yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope the below snippet will do you good. Read inline comments for the basics.

```js
$('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});

$('#add-more').click(function () {  
//add new entry form
  $('#myTable').append('<tr class="t-row"><td><input type="time" onfocus="clearError(this)" class="vTimeStart" /></td><td><input onfocus="clearError(this)" type="time"  value="" class="vTimeEnd" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Delete" /></td></tr>');
});

$('#submit').click(function () {
$('.t-row').each(function(i, obj) { 
    
//Get first time entries
var currentStartTimeValue = $('#myTable .vTimeStart').eq(i).val();
var currentEndTimeValue = $('#myTable .vTimeEnd').eq(i).val(); 
if(i > 0){
//at this point we now have a previous input to validate
//hence we check for validity
var previousIndex = i - 1;
var lastEndTimeValue = $('#myTable .vTimeEnd').eq(previousIndex).val(); 
if(currentStartTimeValue < lastEndTimeValue){
$(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
$(this).attr('title','Current StartTime must be lesser than current EndTime!');
alert('Current StartTime cannot be lesser than previous EndTime');
    return false;
} 
}

if(!currentStartTimeValue){
$(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
$(this).attr('title','Enter value for Start Time!');
alert('Enter value for Start Time!');
    return false;
}else if(!currentEndTimeValue){
$(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
$(this).attr('title','Enter value for End Time!');
alert('Enter value for End Time!');
    return false;
}else if(currentStartTimeValue >= currentEndTimeValue){
$(this).css('background-color','#ff0000');
$(this).attr('title','Current StartTime must be lesser than current EndTime!');
alert('Current StartTime must be lesser than current EndTime');
    return false;
} 

if(i === $('.t-row').length - 1){
//last item in the loop. all good!
alert('All good!');
} 
}); 
}); 

function clearError(el){ 
//reset error state
$(el).parent().closest('tr').css('background','#ffffff');
$(el).parent().closest('tr').attr('title','');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" style="border: 1px solid black">
  <thead>
    <td>
     Start Time
    </td>
    <td>
     End Time
    </td>
    <td>  
    </td>
  </thead>
  <tr class="t-row">
    <td>
      <input type="time" onfocus="clearError(this)" class="vTimeStart" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="time" onfocus="clearError(this)" class="vTimeEnd" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="add-more" type="button" value="Add more">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
```

Comment: I can't see AM PM option.. it was there before.

Comment: I want validations on `Submit` button not on `Add more` button. Means first let them enter all the data and then on `Submit` do validation. How to do this?

Comment: Can you please help?

Comment: thanks. but it shows AM/PM sometimes and sometimes not.